# How to run a process in background on startup?

Tags: startup, daemon, bootable, yocto, ioctl

I'm trying to run a process(myfile) on startup on my yocto linux board, but I'm getting either **IOCTL** or **segmentation fault** while I use **nohup** or **&** to run in background. I could run myfile in background using **setsid**. But, when I tried to run it on startup, that is inside `/etc/init.d`, I got seg fault.
This is what I did -

1. The files that i want to run are in `/home/root`. They are `myfile` with configuration `myfile.conf`. So, I made a file `test.sh` in `/home/root` which contains `setsid /home/root/myfile /home/root/myfile.conf`. 
   If I try to run this  manually it works fine. That is, `./test.sh > /dev/null &`
2. But, I want them to run on startup. So, I make another file called `testcheck.sh` in `/etc/init.d` which contains the path for test.sh and background. That is, `/home/root/test.sh`
3. When I reboot my board, it runs for about 2 seconds then gets killed and  I get an IOCTL segmentation fault error. Kindly help.

**EDIT:** **After few trials, this is what I did (I want to run these 2 files in background during startup - `myfile` and `myfile.conf`)-**

In `/etc/init.d` I created a script called `testcheck.sh` which contains `/home/root/myfile /home/root/myfile.conf > /dev/null &` and when I boot my board, it just runs once (Also, while bootup, i saw the following IOCTL error - `tcgetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device tcsetattr` `ICANON: Inappropriate ioctl for device`).

Comment: Did you get a core file? you can try to gdb the issue your self, check if you have the core file

Comment: try utilising "strace" : 
strace -o /tmp/str.txt setsid /home/...
Then look into the logfile /tmp/str.txt

Comment: Why make the config file setuid? It there anything else in `test.sh` or `testcheck.sh`? You are glossing over a few details, please show (minimal content that fails of) script.

Comment: @camp0 : No, there's no core file.

Comment: @gerhardd. : At the end of the str.txt it says, killed by SIGSEGV.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I used setsid because i wanted the process to be active in the background even when the terminal is closed. No, there's nothing else in both `test.sh` and `testcheck.sh`.

Comment: So probably the best option that you have is to paste the code in some site and try to get feedback from https://stackoverflow.com/, do you have unit tests or code coverage in your code?

Comment: @camp0: That's the issue here. I was given `myfile` and `myfile.conf` by a friend and was asked to run these two in background during startup. 
What I did was - In `/etc/init.d` i created a script called `testcheck.sh` which contains `/home/root/myfile /home/root/myfile.conf > /dev/null &` 
and when i boot my board, it just runs once (Also, while bootup, i saw the following IOCTL error -  `tcgetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device` 
`tcsetattr ICANON: Inappropriate ioctl for device`) .

Comment: we need to see more of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Looks like the process Needs a Controlling terminal. Try running it with "sceen"